# C# WP 8.1 COMException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a WP 8.1 WinRT projrect in which i'm downloading a file and when i get a ResponseInformation statusCode of 200 i attempt to open the file and i get the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error
>   HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

If i open the file by pressing a button the file opens without problems so i guess the problem is calling OpenNow() from HandleDownloadAsync.

Can someone explain me what is the problem ?

```
  private async void HandleDownloadAsync(DownloadOperation download, bool start)
{
     Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(ProgressCallback);
     await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);

     ResponseInformation response = download.GetResponseInformation();

     OpenNow();
}

    private async void OpenNow()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile fileToLaunch = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(medNameChosen + ".pdf");
            if (destinationFile.ToString() != null)
            {
                await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileToLaunch);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error Open Donwloaded File: {0}", ex);
        }
    }
```